unable to import arch_model
Unable to import arch_model and system throwing this  error:
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\np\ufunc\__init__.py in <module>
 1 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
      2 
----> 3 from numba.np.ufunc.decorators import Vectorize, GUVectorize, vectorize, guvectorize
      4 from numba.np.ufunc._internal import PyUFunc_None, PyUFunc_Zero, PyUFunc_One
      5 from numba.np.ufunc import _internal, array_exprs

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\np\ufunc\decorators.py in <module>
      1 import inspect
      2 
----> 3 from numba.np.ufunc import _internal
      4 from numba.np.ufunc.parallel import ParallelUFuncBuilder, ParallelGUFuncBuilder
      5 

SystemError: initialization of _internal failed without raising an exception

I tried uninstalling and installing numpy but that did not work, I have used it before but today it is throwing the error.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

maybe you updated some module and it doesn't work correctly - and this may need to downgrade to older version.
